# Valentine's Day version of Angry Birds?

Tags: angry-birds-seasons

Could someone tell me more about the Valentine's Day version of Angry Birds: Seasons?  I've only recently heard that it exists.  What differentiates it from the other versions that are available?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Valentine's Day Angry Birds was an update to Angry Birds Seasons. The update added more levels with a Valentine's Day theme. Currently there are two paid Angry Birds games out - Angry Birds and Angry Birds Seasons - the Valentine's Day is not a separate app.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Android versions are free, with ads.

Comment: Note: there are now three Angry Birds games with the recent release of *Angry Birds Rio*.